# how can we store a web page form html template along with the user entered data in any server?

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I have and html template where i want to store whole html template along with user data in some directory?
Please let me know if there is any way?. Html template is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSOKI.png).

Answer (score 0):

in principle the HTTP request (from the HTML form) delivers the data entered by the user. I would save that separately (common practise is obviously a DB, but you can also save as JSON file in a directory).
You can always load the HTML and fill the data you need on-the-fly.

If you really want to save the HTML with the data, on your backend you need to get the actual HTML source and manipulate it to add the user data in each field.

Comment: Since this is a one time activity and there are some many fields and the check box's in it.which is the best way to store it in?